# We (have been) are working on this for last two days: the difference between tenses

Tags: present-perfect, present-continuous, continuous

What is the difference between these two sentences:

```
1) We have been working on this for last two days. 

2) We are working on this for last two days
```

Please explain it to me.

Comment: It's been mentioned in the answer below but I think it's worth mentioning directly. It is normal to write _... working on this for **the** last two days_. Missing out the _the_ is possibly some sort of grammar mistake, it's certainly not a common thing to do.

Comment: @Frank: Wouldn't **the** imply *the last 48 hours* as opposed to *the last two calendar days* (say, Monday and Tuesday) if **the** is not used? Or would the omission of **the** be a mistake here?

Comment: @CopperKettle It's the omission of the **the** that seems to be wrong. I'm not a grammar person so I'm not absolutely 100% sure if it is actually wrong but I am a native speaker and it's not something I would ever say and don't think I've ever heard it from a native speaker. I don't think there's a specific 48 hour exactly feeling to it, but it depends what you've been doing for the last two days (or often it would be _the past two days_). You might say _the past few days_ which is even less precise.

Comment: @CopperKettle For precision you'd be much more likely to be precise in your words and say _... for the last 48 hours_. In comparison _the last couple of days, the last two days, the past two days_ are not very precise at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence 1 uses the [Present Perfect Progressive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#Present_perfect_progressive). This tense is used to describe an action that was started in the past and either has just stopped or continues at the moment.

Sentence 2 uses the [Present Continous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_continuous_(English)). This tense is used to describe actions that are taking place now, at this exact moment (in our case), or will take place in the future.

We may use time expressions with the Present Continuous, but these time expressions usually underscore the currency of the action:

> We are working on this / at the moment / currently / now.

I doubt that the time expression **for the last two days** is compatible with the Present Continuous, because two days is quite a stretch of time.

As ColleenV said in a comment below, this time expression effectively puts the action  in the past, which is not okay. With the Present Continuous, our time markers should be either momentous (*now, currently*) or refer to the future (*for the next two days, next Sunday*).

Comment: I think the problem with **for the last two days** is the **last** which puts it in the past and makes it incompatible with _present continous_ tense. _"We are working on this for the next two days."_ would be OK.